# Enabling CLR still doesn't allow me to run code on sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqlclr

I'm using the following command to try and enable the CLR on a SQL Server 2008 instance

```
EXEC sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1
GO

RECONFIGURE
GO
```

But I still get the following error

> Execution of .NET Framework code is disabled. Set "clr enabled"
>   configuration option and restart the server

Do I need to do anything else?

Comment: "restart the server". Is your server a 32bit server?

Comment: Yes I tried that but still no dice

Comment: Then you are doing something incorrect. That's all there is to it.

Comment: Hence my post on here

Comment: What are you trying to do when you get the "Execution of .NET Framework code is disabled." error? When you exec just `EXEC sp_configure 'clr enabled';`, what does it show for the "running" value?

Comment: It's trying to do this when it fails:-  CREATE ASSEMBLY [FileObject]

Comment: What does the log day?

Comment: The log says the same error as above

Comment: Run `sp_configure` by itself. Do you have Windows Fibers / light weight pooling enabled?

Comment: Light weight pooling is not enabled

Comment: Have you applied .NET Framework 2.0 patches? In `sys.dm_clr_properties` what does it show for "state"?

Comment: There haven't been any patches applied as far as I'm aware. The value reads 'locked CLR version with mscoree' for state.

I've tried running this on a few other servers and it seems to be fine on them, it's just this one server that seems to be having problems

Comment: You might have a corrupt .NET DLL. ..it's rare but possible. ..I ran into that one time years ago...there is a command to run in a DOS Window to do a repair. You should also run Windows Update to make sure all .NET Framework patches have been applied.

Comment: Just to confirm, you restarted the Windows server itself, and not just the SQL Server service, correct?

Comment: yes, the whole server has been restarted

Answer (score 4):

To review what has been checked and attempted so far:

1. `EXEC sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1;` has been executed.
2. `RECONFIGURE;` has been executed.
3. The server has been restarted. This should only be
   *necessary* on WOW64 servers.
4. Running `EXEC sp_configure 'clr enabled';` shows a `1` for `run_value`.
5. Running `EXEC sp_configure 'lightweight pooling';` shows a `0` for `run_value`.
6. `state` property in [sys.dm_clr_properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174983.aspx) has a value of "Locked CLR version with mscoree", meaning:

   > The **Locked CLR version with mscoree** state may be seen where the hosted CLR is not being used and, thus, it has not yet been initialized. The hosted CLR is initialized the first time a DDL statement (such as [CREATE ASSEMBLY (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189524.aspx)) or a managed database object is executed.

Additional things to try / check:

1. Make sure that .NET Framework 2.0 and 3.5 SP1 are installed
2. Make sure that .NET Framework patches have been applied through Windows Update
3. Possibly make sure, in **Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features** that "Microsoft SQL Server System CLR Types" is installed
4. Check your authentication type. If set to "both", try change to "Windows Only", restarting the SQL Server service, and see if that helps. Not a good long-term solution, but might point in a direction.
5. What account is the MSSQLSERVER service logging on as? There are some reports that "Network Service" or "NT AUTHORITY\Network Service" might have issues and that Local System account might be preferred.
6. ??

Comment: I'm giving up on this. It's not essential for this server and it's taking up too much of my time. Thanks for your help anyway

Comment: Installing .Net 2.0 and 3.5 resolved this for me - thanks!

Comment: @KevinPope Glad this info help! Thanks for posting what worked for you to help narrow down for others :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
EXEC sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1
go
 RECONFIGURE
go
EXEC sp_configure 'clr enabled'
go
```

Also

> To enable CLR integration, you must have ALTER SETTINGS server level permission, which is implicitly held by members of the sysadmin and serveradmin fixed server roles.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have advanced options enabled?

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

Comment: Yes, I have advanced options enabled

Comment: What is your assembly .NET CLR version? Is it the same as in results of: select * from sys.dm_clr_properties

Comment: CLR enabled is not an advanced option.

Comment: I just got some old code of mine and it was there. I checked now and on MSDN it's also described like that: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms131048(v=sql.100).aspx. Finall I also double checked now and I can execute it without advanced options enabling, which prooves you're right it's not needed.

Comment: Another question is, what account is it running on? If it's a network service, maybe you could try changing it to 'Local System' for a moment and see if it's the same